# Android whether it is possible to create HWND

Tags: java, android, jna

Whether it is possible to create an android HWND?
To call a function of dll i need to pass the variable hwnd.
C:

```
Prototype: int WINAPI AvzOpenDevice(unsigned short uDeviceID, HWND hWnd)
```

This function will draw the image in the window hwnd.

Comment: No.  Android **is not windows** and does not even begin to support the windows graphic APIs.  If you only need to do a small amount of things you might be able to create some sort of minimal re-implementation atop a graphics API that Android does support, but first you would have to take stock of every operation performed by the program you seem to be hoping to port.  Also beware UI thread rules and Activity lifecycle.

Comment: Hey, do you have specs about this DLL? I need some help with a .NET project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> Whether it is possible to create an android HWND?

No.

> To call a function of dll

Android does not have DLLs. Windows has DLLs. Android is not Windows. Windows is not Android. You cannot use a Windows DLL on Android.